# Battery Disconnect Switch: Shank Diameter

Tags: battery, switches

https://www.harborfreight.com/battery-disconnect-switch-97853.html

[image]

The shank-end (in red-circle) is designed to be [connected to an existing negative lead](https://youtu.be/9wLhohfwzoI?t=135).  Attempts install the device on an Integra and Camry failed because the diameter of the shank is not wide enough for a secure fit.

I tried purchasing another similar device from AutoZone, however, the switch had the same problem.  Is there a step or process that I am missing something?

OEM cable diameter is too large for shank:

[image]

Zoom:

[image]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, there's too much wire to fit in the hole? If so, did you try drilling the end out so it was a bit bigger?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2. Good to hear from you.  Do the photos clarify the problem?  The cable does not clamp down on the shank (of the switch) because the shank diameter is smaller than the negative terminal for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the way these are supposed to work is you put an eyelet type connector on the end of your battery wire then attach it with a bolt through the hole you can see in the first photo (on the end where you are trying to connect the clamp to). The new clamp replaces the old. The green knob is there as a quick disconnect. You unscrew the green thumb wheel and then the wire is disconnected without taking the clamp off the battery.

In short, cut off the old clamp and put a new eyelet in its place. Something like this:

[image]

You'll have to figure out the correct size for both the cable (awg size) and the eyelet size for the bolt connector.

Comment: A new cable (that included an eyelet type connector) was installed and replaced the 20+ year old OEM cable.

Answer (score 1):

Get some 12-gauge copper wire and strip off several inches of the insulation.  Wrap the copper strands around the shank of the switch to increase its diameter.  Bolt on your existing negative battery cable.

Comment: A resourceful / clever work-around